# Architecture for avoiding repeated data in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a application where the same data is present in many places in the graph and need to optimize the data queries to avoid processing and sending the same data too often.

As an example consider the following pseudo schema:

```
type Group {
  name: String
  members: [Person]
}
type Person {
  name: String
  email: String
  avatar: Avatar
  follows: [Person]
  followedBy: [Person]
  contacts: [Person]
  groups: [Group]
  bookmarks: [Bookmark]
  sentMessages: [Message]
  receivedMessages: [Message]
}
type Message {
  text: String
  author: Person
  recipients: [Person]
}
type Bookmark {
  message: Message
}
```

Querying a users data can easily contain hundreds, if not thousands, of Person-objects even though it the small circle of friends/contacts/follows only contains tens of distict users.

In my real implementation about 80% of each GraphQL query (in bytes) is redundant and considering that the client does many different queries in the same space above 90% of all data transferred and processed is redundant.

How could I improve the model so that I don't have to load the same data again and again without complicating the client too much?

I'm using Apollo for both GraphQL client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Use/implement pagination (instead of just arrays) for relations - this way you can query for `count`/`total` (render it without array processing) and array of ids only - usually there is no need to query/join person table (DB) at all.

Render list of `Person` components (react?) using passed `id` prop only ... only rendered `Person` fetches for more details (if not cached, use batching to merge requests) consumed/rendered inside.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are actually using pagination where it makes sense, I just didn't think it mattered for this specific question. I have been considering just sending id/ref and seperating the nested Person into a seperate lookup query, it just doesn't seem very GraphQL.

Comment: If you know of anything written on the subject I would really appreciate a pointer.

Comment: graphQL helps with overfetching, apollo helps with reusing already [over-]fetched data ... pagination limits helps with abusing [overfetching] (fetching de facto not used data, fetched 1xx, displayed 1x) ... allows to display quite usable data like 'followed by x, y, z (avatars+infos) and 1xx other (counter)'